# play framework 2.5 move Action.async logic from controller to service

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, controller, playframework-2.5

I have a controller that has many business logic, I would like to move the code inside **Action.async** block of code. This code works, how can I move to another class(service) the code  that is inside of the Action.async?:

```
def tweetsnew(query: String) = Action.async {
// Move From Here...
credentials.map {
  case (consumerKey, requestToken) =>
    ws.url("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json")
      .sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey, requestToken))
      .withQueryString("q" -> query)
      .withQueryString("max_id" -> "833342796736167936")
      .get().map { twitterResponse =>
      if (twitterResponse.status == 200) {
        // Here There Are More Complex Logic
        Ok("That is fine: "+twitterResponse.body)
      } else {
        throw new Exception(s"Could not retrieve tweets for $query query term")
      }
    }
}.getOrElse {
  Future.failed(new Exception("You did not correctly configure the Twitter credentials"))
}
//....To Here. To Another Class
}
```

I have been checked the docummentation, something related to [create a Future[Result]](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAsync) but I am not be able to make that the function returns the same type that Action.async expect.

Comment: Thanks @vdebegue it is a good solution. I would like to propouse another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Action.async` expects a return type of `Future[Result]` so you need to create a function that returns a `Future[Result]`

First step, extract your code to a function:

```scala
object TwitterService {
  def search(query: String, consumerKey: ConsumerKey, requestToken: RequestToken)(implicit ws: WSClient, ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Result] = {
    // your code that make the ws call that returns Ok("...")
  }
 }
```

Then in the controller call your function:

```
def tweetsnew(query: String) = Action.async {
  credentials.map {
    case (consumerKey, requestToken) => TwitterService.search(query, consumerKey, requestToken)
  }.getOrElse {
    // Better to send a bad request or a redirect instead of an Exception
    Future.successful(BadRequest("Credentials not set"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vdebegue. I would like to propouse another solution.
To create a trait in the service like this:
`@ImplementedBy(classOf[TwitterFeed])
trait QueryTweets {
  def queryByWord(query: String): Future[Option[JsValue]]
}`
2)implementing the trait in service, same file:
`class TwitterFeed @Inject() extends QueryTweets {
// A complex code
 Json.parse("""{"changeByObject":"yes"}""")
 Some(aJsonResponse)
}`
3) In Controller:
`def tweetsnew(query: String) = Action.async {
queryTweets.queryByWord(query).flatMap{
 case Some(response) => {
Future.successful(Ok(response))
 }
}
}`

Comment: This also works, it depends when you prefer to inject your dependencies on `WSClient` and `ExecutionContext`. Your way is more "java-ish"